Changing monochromatic image colors while keeping their brightness
I wanted to ask you if someone know a way to make a function in vb.net, that will go through all the received image's pixels and change their color to new (received too) one, while keeping their brightness?
I want an effect that you can illustrate like this (let's say the red one is the received and blue is returned):
red and blue squares, each one with the same relief effect - matching brightness in both.
Is this possible?
I tried using this code (while assuming that this is a monochromatic image and pixels are only in shades of red):
Public Shared Function RecolorKeepingBrightness(ByVal image As Bitmap, ByVal newColor As Color) As Bitmap
    Dim resultImage As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    For x As Integer = 0 To image.Width - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To image. Height - 1
            Dim pixelColor As Color = image.GetPixel(x, y)
            If pixelColor.A > 0 Then
                Dim redIntensity As Double = pixelColor.R / 255.0
                Dim newR As Integer = CInt(newColor.R * redIntensity)
                Dim newG As Integer = CInt(newColor.G * redIntensity)
                Dim newB As Integer = CInt(newColor.B * redIntensity)
                resultImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.A, newR, newG, newB))
            Else
                resultImage.SetPixel(x, y, pixelColor)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return resultImage
End Function

Yet it doesn't work - it can't change colors brighter than 255 0 0. Probably because there are colors brighter than that, f.e. 255 123 123, yet I have no idea how to implement it in code.
I'd be glad for your help and thank you in advance!
PS. It might be as well non-monochromatic image; I just thought it'd be easier to do since I only need this for now.

There are several common false colour palette for mapping monochrome images onto false colours that make tiny variations in intensity more obvious on a colour screen whilst still preserving luminance. Matching red channel luminance using a pure blue image will be tricky since red ~30% luminance green ~59% luminance and blue is a paltry 11%. So for any pixels with a pure red value >93 the luminance cannot be represented by a pure blue pixel. Different colours have different luminosities see for example YCrCb colour space.

You can applying with a ColorMatrix to transform the colors; an example in VB.NET here: Analyze colors of an Image. You could convert to HSL, test the Brightness factor, then correct by both building (and fine-tuning) a matrix for this purpose, and using the ImageAttributes.SetThreshold() method to further adjust the results

A similar method here, used to convert a color image to grayscale, preserving the original brightness. See the two images generated by two different color matrices (one is fine-tuned for the task): the result is quite different, the luminance factor gets lost in translation in one of them

change into color space that has hue, manipulate the hue, change back. use libraries like OpenCV (OpenCVSharp or Emgu). you should rarely write so much code for such a simple operation.
